# how do i add validation on drop down select menu?

Tags: php, validation, html-select

how do i add validation on drop down select menu i have code and i'm working on but problem is that is not working nothing display error message. I want to be display error message if drop down selection values shouldn't be selected before click on add to cart button?

```
if(isset($_REQUEST['check'])){
if (isset($_POST['size']) && $_POST['size'] == '' ) {
echo 'Error, select category';
exit;
}}

<form action="" id="size1" name="size1" method="post"> 
<select style="background-color:#CCC" 
name="size" id="size"  onchange="this.form.submit();" >
<option value="">Select</option>
<option <?php if ($_POST['size'] == 'Small') 
print 'selected '; ?>  value="Small">Small</option>
<option <?php if ($_POST['size'] == 'Medium') 
print 'selected '; ?> value="Medium">Medium</option>
<option  <?php if ($_POST['size'] == 'Large') 
print 'selected '; ?> value="Large">Large</option>
<option   <?php if ($_POST['size'] == 'XL')
print 'selected '; ?> value="XL">XL</option>
</select>

<input type="button" class="button1" name="check" 
value="Add To Cart" onclick="addtocart(<?php echo $row3['id'];?>);" />
</form
```

Answer (score 0):

Please try it's work

it should be like this

```
<?php
    if($_POST['country']=="0")
    {
        echo 'Error, select category';
        //exit;
    }
?>
<form action="" id="size1" name="size1" method="post">
<select style="background-color:#CCC" 
name="size" id="size"  onchange="this.form.submit();" >
  <option value="0">Select</option>
  <option <?php if ($_POST['size'] == 'Small') 
print 'selected '; ?>  value="Small">Small</option>
  <option <?php if ($_POST['size'] == 'Medium') 
print 'selected '; ?> value="Medium">Medium</option>
  <option  <?php if ($_POST['size'] == 'Large') 
print 'selected '; ?> value="Large">Large</option>
  <option   <?php if ($_POST['size'] == 'XL')
print 'selected '; ?> value="XL">XL</option>
</select>
<input type="button" class="button1" name="check" 
value="Add To Cart" onclick="addtocart(<?php echo $row3['id'];?>);" />
</form>
```

Answer (score 0):

If I get your question right, you wish to validate before the form gets submitted? If so, then you need to use client side validation:

http://docs.jquery.com/Plugins/validation#Example

Answer (score 0):

make u smal change in html here

```
<option value="0">Select</option>
```

and function like this to check

```
function check_selected_or_not(){
var check_selected = jQuery('#size').val();
if (check_selected == 0){
    alert('Please select');
}else{
    alert('sucess');
}

}
```

Comment: @farhan call his function from your `addtocart` function